# Software to whitelist a number of programs to run and block the rest in Linux

Tags: linux

I am looking for ways to whitelist the programs under Linux.

Comment: I am not a specialist, but apparently SELinux has "*Controls over process initialization and inheritance, and program execution*",

Comment: Do you want to block execution for a particular user? Do you want root to still be able to execute everything, or not?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul thanks but if you are more ideas, I am looking for 4 to 5 ways.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul yes root is included with other users to follow whitelist.

Comment: If you want to block `root` from using software, simply uninstalling the software is the best way. Remember, `root` has no real limits, unless those limits are imposed by an external system (ie, file permissions on a mounted network drive - remove system could enforce read-only, no execute, etc)

Comment: @ivanivan Understood, and suggestions for other users. Thanks!